# Excel VBA: How to convert numbers to ranges

Tags: vba

I have some numbers and I want to list their ranges

```
0O6X6768
0O6X6769
0O6X7468
0O6X7469
0O6X7470
0O6X7477
0O6X7478
0O6X7479
0O6X7482
0O6X9383
```

Like these, I want to turn them into

```
0O6X6768 0O6X6769 0O6X7468~0O6X7470 0O6X7477~0O6X7479 0O6X7482 0O6X9383
```

The first three characters will be the same, but the third to fourth characters will change, so I wrote a judgment

```
IsNumeric(Right(Cells(i, "A"), 4))
```

If TRUE then

```
CInt(Right(Cells(i, "A"), 4))
```

If Flase then

```
CInt(Right(Cells(i, "A"), 3))
```

convert them to numbers and then subtract the next cell from this one to determine if it is 1

But this way

```
0O6X6768 0O6X6769
```

will become

```
0O6X6768~0O6X6769
```

I think there should be a better solution, how should I do it?

Here are some examples

[examples.xlsx download](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18IvghR5_dhXCYa22PCu0_ty9NM7KGmMI/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104270337929543772984&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Thank you all.

Comment: What "Ranges" are you talking about? Excel `ranges`? Are all the strings you show in a cell, or each row exists in a cell? How/where do you want returning the processed pseudo "ranges"?

Comment: If "0O6X7468~0O6X7470" why not "0O6X6768~0O6X6769", too? The rule of grouping should be applied only for more than 3 consecutive  numbers? I looked to the example you shared and it looks inconsistent. In column A:A and C:C the rule you try defining is not valid, anymore. The string "0O60S506" contains an "S" as the fifth character...

Comment: @FaneDuru yes,The rule  grouping should be applied only for more than 3 consecutive numbers

Comment: @FaneDuru 0O60S506 -> IsNumeric(Right(Cells(i, "A"), 4)) ,Here will be the FALSE ,Therefore, he will apply CInt(Right(Cells(i, "A"), 3)) ,Take the three numbers on the right